# Sequences and divisibility

Tags: sequences-and-series, divisibility

Im a high school student attempting to do this and would like some ideas for the following problem. Im completely stuck in the blind and have no.idea how to proceed. Thanks. 
Edit: Im so sorry the paper i picked it from had a typo Ive corrected it now and it was rather easy to prove. The first 2 terms had been switched around.

Consider the following sequence where
$$ y_{1}=1, y_{2}=2018$$ and $$y_{k+1}=2018y_k + 2019y_{k-1}$$ for $k\ge 2$ 
Show that there must exist a term in the sequence divisible by $2018^ {2018}$

Comment: Downvoted as your question shows zero effort. Please read MSE's guidelines.

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Better ?okay now ?

Comment: It looks good now! +1

Comment: Any idea of how i can go about this. The formula below isnt of much help.

Comment: This looks quite tricky. You have to get up to $n=4035$ just to get a factor of  $2018^2$.

Comment: Do you think its possible to use mod arithmetic to rule out cases because 2 consecutive terms always add to powers of 2019 and alternating terms differ by a power of 2019*(2018)

Answer (score 2):

it is easy to prove that $$y_k=\frac{2019^k-4074341 (-1)^k}{2020}$$ and this will help you

Comment: I did this. Through rearranging and using geometric sums, but I thought this was of no use at all. Thanks. Ill look into what this can be used for.

Comment: I still cant get any further despite trying to rearrange it further. I tried thinking in terms of mods of 2018^2018 too but there is no evidence they repeat